# Spring security JWT filter throws 500 and HTML instead of 401 and json

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've been having trouble getting security working correctly, half of the problem was fixed with this
[Spring Boot Security wont ignore certain paths that dont need to be secured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900937/spring-boot-security-wont-ignore-certain-paths-that-dont-need-to-be-secured/62901277?noredirect=1#comment111235291_62901277)
Second problem is spring is ignoring the HTTP status code on failure and always throws a 500.

When the JWT token is invalid I want to return a 401 and a json response. I keep getting a 500 and the white label html page.
JwtFilter

```
class JwtFilter(private val tokenService: TokenService) : GenericFilterBean() {

    override fun doFilter(req: ServletRequest, res: ServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {

        val request = req as HttpServletRequest
        val response = res as HttpServletResponse

        val httpRequest = request as HttpServletRequest
        val path = httpRequest.servletPath.toString().substring(0, 12)
        if (path == "/api/v1/auth") {
            chain.doFilter(req, res)
            return
        } else {
            val token = TokenUtil.extractToken(request as HttpServletRequest)

            if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty()) {
                try {
                    tokenService.getClaims(token)
                } catch (e: SignatureException) {
                    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid JWT Signature")
                } catch (e: MalformedJwtException) {
                    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid JWT token")
                } catch (e: ExpiredJwtException) {
                    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Expired JWT token")
                } catch (e: UnsupportedJwtException) {
                    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Unsupported JWT exception")
                } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Jwt claims string is empty")
                }
            } else {
                throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "Missing auth token")
            }
            chain.doFilter(req, res)
        }
    }
}
```

In my application class too I also have

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration::class])
```

Everywhere else in the application ResponseStatusException throws an error with the correct code and in JSON format, here for example when I throw an exception the response will be HTML like

<!doctype html>

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
    
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
        }

```
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    b {
        color: white;
        background-color: #525D76;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    a {
        color: black;
    }

    .line {
        height: 1px;
        background-color: #525D76;
        border: none;
    }
</style>
```

## HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

**Type** Exception Report

**Message** 401 UNAUTHORIZED "Expired JWT token"

**Description** The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED "Expired JWT token"
    events.slap.app.web.security.JwtFilter.doFilter(JwtFilter.kt:40)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
```

**Note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.35

Comment: I still don't get why you're writing your own filter & oauth support. It's all available out of the box in Spring/Spring Boot. The authorization server, if you are being OCD, is temporarily deprecated while its being rewritten (which most people think is pretty stupid -- rewrite it, THEN deprecate the old version lol). Imo, that's still no reason to write your own vs. a battle tested solution. You could also use Keycloak, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of throwing exceptions in the filter, do this

```
    response.sendsetStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
    return;
```

or if you want message as well

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("{ ");
    sb.append("\"error\": \"Unauthorized\" ");
    sb.append("\"message\": \"Unauthorized\"");<--- your message here
    sb.append("\"path\": \"")
      .append(request.getRequestURL())
      .append("\"");
    sb.append("} ");

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);  
    response.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
    return;
```

Comment: This works properly!
but i think that will be
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been bothered me around three-day and thanks @Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai 's comment.

Following is the way I did

```
        if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty()) {
            String msg = new String();
            try {
                tokenService.getClaims(token)
            } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            msg = "Invalid JWT signature";
            } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            msg = "Invalid JWT token";
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            msg = "Expired JWT token";
            } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            msg = "Unsupported JWT token";
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            msg = "JWT claims string is empty.";
            }
        if (msg.isNotEmpty()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("{ ");
            sb.append("\"error\": \"Unauthorized\",");
            sb.append("\"message\": \"Invalid Token.\",");
            sb.append("\"path\": \"")
            .append(request.getRequestURL())
            .append("\"");
            sb.append("} ");
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            response.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
            return;
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up an `ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint` that is used by  SecurityWebFilterChain (comes with @EnableWebFluxSecurity) you can use this

```
class  HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint
```

For some reason, I got 500 thrown instead of 401 when I tried to implement my own EntryPoint. It however works as expected and throws 401 now.